# How to match the axes of two plots with Bokeh?

Tags: python, range, bokeh, figure, yaxis

I have 2 plots...

```
vwc_fig = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height=400, title="Volumetric Water Content",
                x_axis_type="datetime",
                )
vwc_fig2 = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height=400, title="Volumetric Water Content",
                 x_axis_type="datetime",
                 )
```

I then set then data...

```
pr = vwc_fig.line(x="date_time", y="P3_VWC",
            legend_label = 'pine road 45 cm',
             line_color = 'blue',
            source=pine_rd_df)
l = vwc_fig2.line(x="date_time", y="P3_VWC",
            legend_label = 'lukens 28 cm',
            line_color = 'green',
            source=lukens_df)
```

But I want to make sure that the y-axis for both graphs is the same range so that the graphs are comparable. Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried creating the 2nd figure to have a y_range equal to that of the first figure...

```
vwc_fig = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height=400, title="Volumetric Water Content",
                x_axis_type="datetime",
                )
vwc_fig2 = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height=400, y_range=vwc_fig.y_range, title="Volumetric Water Content",
                 x_axis_type="datetime",
                 )
```

But that did not work. No errors came up and the graphs looked no different. I also tried other methods like manually setting up the ranges but that also does not work. For example...

```
vwc_fig2.yaxis.ticker = [10, 20, 37.4]
vwc_fig2.yaxis.bounds = [10, 37.4]
```

Changing the ticker or bounds resulted in my y-axis labels disappearing all together but still no errors came up. Any tips on how I could achieve this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sharing range objects is the usual method of doing this, so you will need to elaborate on what "that did not work" actually means in detail. There was an error? In Python or the browser JS console? What was the exact error message? Or the plot mis-rendered? Or didn't render at all?

Comment: The errors that came up (or lack thereof) have been updated. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you will really need to provide a *complete* [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 so that it can be properly investigated directly.

Answer (score 1):

The range in bokeh is specified by a tuple giving (min, max). So in your case I would set the same y-range for both graphs.

As seen from your example, add:

```
vwc_fig = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height=400, title="Volumetric Water Content",
                 x_axis_type="datetime", y_range=(10, 37.4))
vwc_fig2 = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height=400, title="Volumetric Water Content", 
                  x_axis_type="datetime", y_range=(10, 37.4))
```

and then both should have the same y-range.